# How to pass QueryString in anchor tag to edit User profile?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I am working on a web based application. In this application when user click to `EditProfile` then he/she would be redirected to `CPUserMaster.Aspx` page with his stored values. How could i pass the `userid` from `querystring` inside `Anchor tag` ?

here is my code

```
<!--userinfo-->
                <div class="userinfodrop">
                    <div class="userdata">
                        <h4>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_loginnamelarge" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </h4>
                        <span class="email"></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='<%# Eval("UserId", "CPUserMaster.aspx?uid={0}" ) %>'>Edit Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.aspx">Sign Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--userdata-->
```

Comment: Are you using this code inside any databound control like gridview.

Comment: No Sir! this code used for display the user profile information at top right panel. @Gaurav Jain

Answer (score 0):

You can provide href to anchor tag from .cs page.You have to add runat attribute first to anchor tag
like this.

1)  a id="a_link" href='' runat="server">Edit Profile

after that edit .cs page and add this code on page_load event

2)  a_link.Attributes.Add("href", your url with querystring);

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
<a href="CPUserMaster.aspx?uid=<%# Eval("UserId") %>">Edit Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to read from query string and redirecting to another location and want to pass that retrieved value in query string as I could understand your problem. here is what you can change in your code-

```
            <div class="userinfodrop">
                <div class="userdata">
                    <h4>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_loginnamelarge" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </h4>
                    <span class="email"></span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="CPUserMaster.aspx?uid=<%# Request.QueryString["UserId"]%>">Edit Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.aspx">Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--userdata-->
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it like this instead of href make a link button then in .cs file on click event of link Button write this code..

> Response.Redirect("Page.aspx?Data="+Server.UrlEncode(string));

Answer (score 0):

### I hope this is use full for you##

```html
<a href="CPUserMaster.aspx?uid=<%# Eval('UserId') %>">Edit Profile</a>
```

<a href="CPUserMaster.aspx?uid=<%# Eval("UserId") %>">Edit Profile

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I agree with you, but when question Already is a Describe, then what is the need to Describe this?